# ggplot2 in combination with extension libraries

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can I combine basic geom_* layers with "stat" properties from third party libraries? And basic ggplot stat_* layers with geoms from another libraries.

I have simple example:

```
require(ggrepel)    
Plot1<- ggplot(data=mpg, aes(x=cty, y=hwy)) + 
    geom_point()+
    stat_sum(aes(label=..n..), alpha=.5, colour=c("red"), size=3, geom="text")
```

In this example I want to replace the "text" geom with third party "geom_text_repel" from ggrepel package. In the case I change the property geom="text" to geom="text_repel", an error message appears:

> Error: Found object is not a geom.

Similar error appears in the case I want to use third party stat in ggplot2 geom_* layer.

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

This code works on my `R 3.4.1` (`ggplot2_2.2.1.9000` and `ggrepel_0.6.5`):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)    
Plot1 <- ggplot(data=mpg, aes(x=cty, y=hwy)) + 
    geom_point() +
    stat_sum(aes(label=..n..), alpha=.5, colour=c("red"), size=3, geom="text_repel")
Plot1
```

[image]